# What's the best way to list object's many-to-many references as well as lack of such references to a set?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a simple site. There are some masters who provide services from a certain list, which admins create and maintain. Any given master can provide a subset of services, he can provide a given service only one time or none at all, and do so at a certain price. Here's what I have so far, it's pretty obvious:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Master(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, through='MasterService')

class MasterService(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # masters can avoid listing the exact price if they want

    class Meta:
        unique_together=("master", "service")
```

But when I present the master in a view, I want to list all available services — including those that given master doesn't provide, with appropriate comment. What's the best way to achieve this functionality?

I have these possible solutions:

- Create a special helper class in a viewer, which consists of MasterService and a special boolean which indicates whether the service is available at all. Each time the view for a certain master is called, compose list of objects of this class for every possible service. Seems easy but not elegant.
- Create this special boolean field in MasterService class itself. That way I'll have to create and save in database MasterService object for any Master*Service combination, which seems excessive.
- Pass all available services into the master view template and iterate over them in the template, checking each of them if they exist in master.masterservice_set. Seems the best way, but I don't understand how to do that with django's template system.

P.S.: I not only seek the possible solution how to do that functionality, but wish to learn the best way that correlates with django's and python ideology, which still seem pretty foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/
and

```
import this
```

to get the python philosophy from the interpreter.

That's for the philosophy.

Creating a class may be heavy if it can be done in one function. Not elegant, you said it.
Creating a stored boolean ... Excessive, you said it.

Then the third proposition. Close enough! 
"master view template"
If you want to iterate with some checks, it's in the 'view', the logic permits it. Not in the template, which is presentation- not processing- of data, which receive the processed data just to display it.